# Eeeek! SE Android app crashes a lot after latest beta update (v1.0.66)

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app, posts

The latest beta update made the app crash a lot:

- when I press 'Add comment'.
- after deleting a comment.
- after up/down/unvoting a post (happened when I upvoted an answer)
- after editing a post (but the edit is applied).

Spec: Nexus 5 on Lollipop 5.1.1, SE App v1.0.66 (beta)

Comment: I can reproduce this on a Moto G with Android 5.1, also the beta version of the SE app.

Comment: Looking into this

Comment: I just experienced this myself today. @Kasra does it actually help you if we hit the "report" button on the crash notices?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Yes! They're automatically tracked using Fabric but it's always great to get more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.67, which is being released right now. It'll be live when this post is 2 hours old.